# How to capture command line parameters for new processes?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to capture the video conversion parameters passed onto the codecs in [MediaCoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaCoder) to learn how codecs pass streams onto other codecs. Is there a program that captures the command-line parameters/arguments of newly created processes, either system-wide or processes spawned under one process?

Answer (score 9):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can show you command line params of current processes.

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can log all activities, including process creations. To see just them, add a filter "Operation is Process Create".